# Repeated frames when reading files from directory using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using openCV on C++. In my program I am accessing all the images in a directory using glob function of openCV. And then I am reading and showing the images using imread and imshow functions of openCV.

My image sequence is :
[Black frame - White frame] ---- x50

However the sequence I am getting displayed on screen has some repetition of black frame. I looks like openCV is not reading the files as they are stored in the directory.

Do someone know why this is happening? Did someone encountered similar problem with openCV before?

Here is my code:

```
    void ImageDisp()
    {
        vector<String> filenames;
        String folder = "C:\\Users\\aamir\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\BWSeq_test\\";  
         glob(folder, filenames);
         namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL); 
         cvSetWindowProperty("MyWindow", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

         for (size_t i = 0; i < filenames.size() - 1; i++)
         {  
            printf("----------Changing Image--------\n ");
            int k = 0;
`           Mat img = imread(filenames[i], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
            while (k < 100)
            { 
            imshow("MyWindow", img); 
            waitKey(1);
            ShowCursor(false);
            k = k + 1;
            }
         }
         destroyWindow("MyWindow"); 
         return 0;
     }
```

Comment: No one will be able to help you if you do not show your code.

Comment: You can sort the `vector<String>` created from `glob`, if needed. Please add more details

Comment: I have edited my post and added my code. Kindly help if anyone knows whats wrong with my code. Thanks